# How can I display images using the absolute path with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem displaying images when hosting the site. Locally, I was using the dynamic link to display images, but it only works locally. My images are stored in the : : **storage/app/public/Images tree**.

```
<div class="card-bg" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('storage/ServiceImages/' .$service->service_image) }}');" ></div>
```

and this

```
<img src="/storage/ActualityImages/{{$actualite->actuality_image}}" class="img-fluid" alt="" style="height: 200px; object-fit: cover;">
```

Using both approaches the images are displayed locally but not online. and I'm asked to use the absolute path, I've done so but without success.

Comment: and what URL does the that call to `asset` generate?

Comment: Why use `ServiceImages/` and `ActualityImages/` as folder when they are in an `Images/` folder?

Comment: the site web/storage/ActualityImages/17039931090.jpg 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: No, I have different folders for my activities. I have an ActualityImages, ServicesImages and ProductImages folder.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link` on your server?

Comment: I've used the symbolic link, locally it works. and the person guiding me told me not to use the symbolic link but the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the Storage folder
And run this again on your server

```
Php artisan storage:link
```

However if you don't have SSH access to the Terminal

You can store the public files in the **public folder without any symlinks

Here's how u can do it

```
In filesystems.php
```

Change this code

```
'root' => storage_path('app/public'), 
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
```

With this

```
'root' => public_path(), 
 'url' => env('APP_URL'),
```

An then u access you image

https://yourwebsite.com/ActualityImages/$imagename